# comparing data line by line from two large files

Tags: java

I need to analyze differences between two large data files which should each have identical structures.  Each file is a couple of gigabytes in size, with perhaps 30 million lines or text data.  The data files are so large that I hesitate to load each into its own array, when it might be easier to just iterate through the lines in order.  Each line has the structure:

```
topicIdx, recordIdx, other fields...
```

topicIdx and recordIdx are sequential, starting at zero and incrementing +1 with each iteration, so it is easy to find them in the files. (No searching around required; just increment forward in order).

I need to do something like:

```
for each line in fileA  
    store line in String itemsA  
       get topicIdx and recordIdx  
           find line in fileB with same topicIdx and recordIdx  
               if exists  
                   store this line in string itemsB  
                       for each item in itemsA  
                           compare value with same index in itemsB  
                               if these two items are not virtually equal  
                                   //do something  
                else  
                    //do something else
```

I wrote the following code with FileReader and BufferedReader, but the apis for these do not seem to provide the functionality that I need.  Can anyone show me how to fix the code below so that it accomplishes what I desire?

```
void checkData(){  
    FileReader FileReaderA;  
    FileReader FileReaderB;  
    int topicIdx = 0;  
    int recordIdx = 0;  
    try {  
        int numLines = 0;
        FileReaderA = new FileReader("B:\\mypath\\fileA.txt");  
        FileReaderB = new FileReader("B:\\mypath\\fileB.txt");  
        BufferedReader readerA = new BufferedReader(FileReaderA);  
        BufferedReader readerB = new BufferedReader(FileReaderB);
        String lineA = null;
        while ((lineA = readerA.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineA != null && !lineA.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> itemsA = Arrays.asList(lineA.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                topicIdx = Integer.parseInt(itemsA.get(0));
                recordIdx = Integer.parseInt(itemsA.get(1));
                String lineB = null;
                //lineB = readerB.readLine();//i know this syntax is wrong
                setB = rows from FileReaderB where itemsB.get(0).equals(itemsA.get(0));
                for each lineB in setB{
                    List<String> itemsB = Arrays.asList(lineB.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                    for(int m = 0;m<itemsB.size();m++){}
                    for(int j=0;j<itemsA.size();j++){  
                    double myDblA = Double.parseDouble(itemsA.get(j));  
                    double myDblB = Double.parseDouble(itemsB.get(j));  
                    if(Math.abs(myDblA-myDblB)>0.0001){  
                        //do something  
                    }  
                 }  
            }  
        }  
        readerA.close();  
    }   catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
}
```

Comment: If you are comparing data, go line by line. If you're comparing binary or files, go byte by byte. My intuition tells me Line endings are something I don't think you know about yet.

Comment: I would start with replacing the pseudocode with Java code

Comment: Java is way too slow for operations like this. You should write it in assembly instead. :)

Comment: where's the downvote button for comments?? :)

Comment: @Jashaszun  This is just for my own analysis a few times, not for production, so waiting an hour for it to run in Java while I do other things is faster than learning to write it in assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both files sorted by your search keys (recordIdx and topicIdx), so you can do kind of a merge operation like this

```
open file 1
open file 2
read lineA from file1
read lineB from file2
while (there is lineA and lineB) 
    if (key lineB < key lineA) 
        read lineB from file 2
        continue loop
    if (key lineB > key lineA)
        read lineA from file 1
        continue
    // at this point, you have lineA and lineB with matching keys
    process your data
    read lineB from file 2
```

Note that you'll only ever have two records in memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need this in Java, why not use [java-diff-utils](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/) ? It implements a well known diff algorithm.

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  Same comment as I left for Dale Wilson.

Answer (score 1):

Consider https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/.   Let someone else do the heavy lifting.

Comment: The files have subtle differences, like one file has perhaps 20 decimal places, while the other file has perhaps one decimal place.  And one file uses infinity, while the other gives a very large number for infinity.  I know how to address such differences in java...I just do not know how to get this much data into arraylists without splitting them into many multiple files first.